# Powershell capture multiple values?

Tags: regex, powershell

The following code returns only one match.

```
$s = 'x.a,
x.b,
x.c
'
$s -match 'x\.(.*?)[,$]'
$Matches.Count # return 2
$Matches[1] # returns a only
```

Excepted to return `a, b, c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator only finds the first match. The `-AllMatches` with `Select-String` will fetch all matches in the input. Also, `[,$]` matches a `,` or `$` literal chars, the `$` is not a string/line end metacharacter.

A possible solution may look like

```
 Select-String 'x\.([^,]+)' -input $s -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

The pattern is `x\.([^,]+)`, it matches `x.` and then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `,`.

Comment: Tried both solutions and found out only the first one works though.

Comment: Ok, I could not check the other one (that approach requires one of the more recent PS versions than what I have on this machine)